# apache2 crit error file util_ldap.c, line 85, assertion "0" failed

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd, webserver, http

I have simple webservice with one index.html file with  hello world
And I'm trying to make this website accessible only with LDAP authentication, but when I trying to access website errors start occur. Maybe someone know how to fix this? Error :

```
[Fri Dec 02 08:30:19.071039 2022] [ldap:crit] [pid 3659377] (13)Permission denied: [client x.x.x.x:58573] AH10134: LDAP cache lock failed
[Fri Dec 02 08:30:19.071176 2022] [core:crit] [pid 3659377] AH00102: [Fri Dec 02 08:30:19 2022] file util_ldap.c, line 85, assertion "0" failed
```

apache2 LDAP config file looks like:

```
<Location />
 AuthType Basic
AuthName "Apache LDAP authentication"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://domain.xx.x:389/OU=Domain Users,DC=domain,DC=xx,DC=x?sAMAccountName"
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=apache_ldap,OU=Apache,OU=Services Accounts,DC=domain,DC=xx,DC=x"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "pass"
Require valid-user

</Location>


apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
 ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
 Main DocumentRoot: "/etc/apache2/htdocs"
 Main ErrorLog: "/etc/apache2/logs/error_log"
 Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
 Mutex rewrite-map: dir="/run/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
 Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
 Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
 Mutex proxy: using_defaults
 Mutex ldap-cache: using_defaults
 Mutex ssl-cache: dir="/run/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
 Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=sysvsem
 PidFile: "/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
 Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
 Define: MODSEC_2.5
 Define: MODSEC_2.9
 User: name="nobody" id=99
 Group: name="nobody" id=99
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.54 (cPanel)
[image]

Comment: SELinux enabled? Please post output of `sestatus`.

Comment: Disabled.SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: Thanks. Could you enable detailed debug logging for Apache by setting `LogLevel debug` and edit your post containing the relevant debug lines for the LDAP module?

Comment: This already debug :D 
[Fri Dec 02 11:26:48.187947 2022] [ldap:crit] [pid 3720963] (13)Permission denied: [client 185.x.x.x.x:49907] AH10134: LDAP cache lock failed
[Fri Dec 02 11:26:48.188115 2022] [core:crit] [pid 3720963] AH00102: [Fri Dec 02 11:26:48 2022] file util_ldap.c, line 85, assertion "0" failed
[Fri Dec 02 11:26:48.302951 2022] [core:notice] [pid 2340053] AH00052: child pid 3720963 exit signal Aborted (6)

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you use file-based Mutexes or other special Mutex config? (Check for all occurences of `Mutex` in your configuration, both vhost and global.) If so, try disabling file-based Mutexes by adding an exception for ldap, like so: `Mutex sem ldap-cache`.

Comment: updated with screenshot, only those two lines with Mutex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141001/discussion-between-edward-and-robotiaga).